# aggregate Array of Tuples in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I created a ClickHouse Table using the following code

```
CREATE TABLE meetings
(
    _id UInt64,
    records Array(Tuple(a String, b UInt64, c String))
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY (_id);
```

Describing the table gave the following columns

_id -> UInt64

records.a -> Array(String)

records.b -> UInt64

records.c -> Array(String)

I now need an aggregation of records.b grouped by record.a

If I insert the following data

> [{a: 'interview', b: 3, c: 'x'}, {a: 'sync', b: 2, c: 'y'}],[{a:'interview', b: 11, c: 'l'}]

I need the following as output

> {'interview': 14, 'sync': 2}

Answer (score 1):

Found it

```
Select sumMap(mapFromArrays(categories.a, categories.b)) as meeting_time_total 
from meetings;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```sql
SELECT
    a,
    sum(b)
FROM meetings
ARRAY JOIN
    records.a AS a,
    records.b AS b
GROUP BY a

/*
┌─a─────────┬─sum(b)─┐
│ sync      │      2 │
│ interview │     14 │
└───────────┴────────┘
*/
```

Comment: But doesn't this create an matrix of size nxm and then do the aggregation ?